# validate data type at the time of user input

Tags: java, validation, int, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I want to validate the data type, (in my case it is 'int'), at the time of user input using Scanner.

I wrote code below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter size of an array...");
    int n = 0;

     // 1st block, n <= 100
    do {
        System.out.println("Capacity must be less than or equal to 100");
        try {
            n = scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Enter only integers ");
        }
    } while (n > 100);

    int[] arr = new int[n];

    // block 2. Value must be greater than 0 and less than 10000
    for (int i = 0; i < n;) {
        do {
            try {
                arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Enter only integer value");
            }
        } while (arr[i] > 10000 || arr[i] < 1);
        i++;
    }

    scanner.close();

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Issue is,
in 1st block, if i give character, program terminates. **"How to keep loop running on failed validation??"**

in 2nd block if i give non integer, it runs infinitely with message, "Enter only integer value".

**From debug, i conclude that, Without waiting for input it takes last non-int value which was provided before.**

**Why compiler is taking last value??**

Any suggestion ?

Comment: My first suggestion would be that you split up your code into individual methods. It might seem like a weird suggestion given the length of your code, but this way you can take care of one piece of functionality at a time, which should make it easier to understand your own code, get these individual pieces to work properly and easily plug them together. For example, for the first part of your code, you could write a message `getIntInput()` or somesuch that returns an indicative value of `-1` if the user entered something non-numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You assign `0` as default value of the `n` integer you are using to get the user input : `int n = 0;` 
So if the input triggers a `InputMismatchException`, you arrive in the `while` statement with a `n` that equals `0` and `while (n > 100)` with `n = 0` is `false`. 
So you exit the loop.
To solve this problem :

- use a wrapper Integer : `Integer n = null;` that has a nullable value allows to know if no value was accepted in the scanner reading
- change the `while` statement condition to check your requirement :

  `while (n == null || n > 100);`

2) For first case as for the second case, if the input doesn't match with the type required (here a `int` value), the current token in the scanner is not read.
Just ignore this token to avoid entering in an infinite loop :

```
   catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        ...
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: Upvoted for you took the time to understand OPs code and provide not only a solution but also an explanation. Just one thing: I feel like it might be a nicer solution to use an indicative value in case of `InputMismatchException` (let's say `-1` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`) instead of using `Integer` instead of `int`. Of course, that's a matter of taste.

Comment: @davidxxx, for both block answer lies on ignoring current token. I used scanner.nextLine on both cases and problem is solved. No need for wrapper integer.
Thanks :)

Comment: @domdom I like your idea of indicative value. Unfortunately i can upvote because of low rank. I appreciate it.

Comment: @domdom Thank your for your feedback. Indeed in the op case it may be a little bit simpler and it seems suited. Using `null` could have a little advantage If we want to make the distinction between not accepted values that are not integers and not accepted values that are integers but not in the good range, without introducing other variables. With `(n == -1);` you don't know necessarily if the user has entered `-1` or a not integer value.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to davidxxx's answer:
Here's the same code using Scanner.hasNextInt() method.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter size of an array...");
while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) scanner.next();
int arrayLength = scanner.nextInt();

int[] arr = new int[arrayLength];

boolean arrayFull = false;
int index = 0;

System.out.println("Enter array values");
while (!arrayFull){
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) scanner.next();
    int value = scanner.nextInt();
    if (value < 0 || value > 1000) {
        System.out.println("Enter only integer value < 0 and > 1000");
        continue;
    }
    arr[index++] = value;

    if (index >= arrayLength){
        arrayFull = true;
    }
}
```